# Will Ubuntu work with my mac book pro I7, 8gb ram, and 500gb hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, apple

I bought a used Mac Book Pro laptop. I think it's about a 2011 or 12 model. Anyway, coming from a PC World, I didn't know (until I contacted online Apple Support) that the other guy that sold it. I bought it from a pawn shop was supposed to format it, and then I'd be able to download the OS and reinstall, etc,. but the problem with even that solution is that the mother board had been replaced and didn't have a serial number, so I can't even do that. I can't get upgrades, etc, so I've just left the OS on it that's on it. I use my version of Apples I tunes, but I'm considering getting rid of the Apple OS completely, otherwise I'd have to take it to the apple store and have them do all the work at a price I probably don't want to pay. 
So, my apple notebook / mac book pro has an I7 Intel Chip, 8 gig of RAM, and a 500 gb 7200 RPM  hard drive, but I also have an external hard drive of the same. 
Will Ubuntu install as a dual boot at least, or even could I install Ubuntu and delete the OS from Apple? Would it work? I'm thinking I could at least do the dual boot and use ubuntu until I have it the way I want it configured and it works with all the hardware and I have all the drivers I need, then delete the OS from apple? Would that be a smart route?
Thanks so much in advance. 
Tim

Answer (score 2):

It should work just fine. As a recommendation use the [64-bit image of Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) because it's long term support and will provide updates and support for a couple of years while 14.10 will only last a couple on months. Yes you can dual boot. I see from your  description that you might still want to keep OS X for a while. So also as a recommendation: tick the option `install Ubuntu alongside`, Mac OS X in your case and not to replace Mac OS X. Later you can get rid of Mac OS X(or Ubuntu) if you so decide and extend Ubuntu to use the full HDD.

[image: the install alongside option]